# invalid initialization of non-const reference of type ' ' from an rvalue of type ' '

Tags: c++, netbeans

I have a proble with my code.

```
class RefC
{
    public:
        std::string cCommit;
        std::list<Commit>::iterator itc;

        RefC(
            const std::string &cod,
            const std::list<Commit>::iterator &it = std::list<Commit>::iterator()
        ):cCommit(cod), itc(it) {}

        RefC( const RefC &orig )
            : cCommit( orig.cCommit ), itc( orig.itc ) {}

        bool operator<(const RefC &rc) const
        {
            return cCommit < rc.cCommit;
        }
};
```

This is my RefC class, but when I call her to do:

```
indiceCommits.insertar(RefC(comm.getCodigo(),itc));
```

This give me

> invalid initialization of non-const reference of type 'GitCode::RefC&' from an rvalue of type 'GitCode::RefC'

why? How can I solve it?

Thanks ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not in your RefC class but in the declaration of the insertar() function. I guess it looks like

```
insertar( RefC& r);
```

but you want to pass a temporary object (rvalue), which is only possible if the parameter type is const-ref

```
insertar( const RefC& r);
```

rvalue means a value that can only be on the right side of an assignment, e.g. x = y, x must be an lvalue, usually something with a name, something to which a value can be assigned to, whereas an rvalue (y) can be a constant, a literal, a temporary object etc.